# Laravel test unable to find a file at path using Storage::fake()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have created my own 'disk' in `config/filesystems.php` which looks like so;

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public') . '/uploads'
],
```

This seems to work fine when in my controller, it uploads the file and returns a response. my code is as follows;

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
        foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
            $fileName = md5($image . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'uploads');
        }
    }

    // return goes here
}
```

but when I go to test my store method using the following code;

```
public function testUserCanSuccessfullySubmitSingleImage(): void
{
    Storage::fake('uploads');

    $this->postJson('/upload', [
        'filename' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('image1.jpg')
    ]);

    Storage::disk('uploads')->assertExists('image1.jpg');
    Storage::disk('uploads')->assertMissing('missing.jpg');
}
```

I get the following error;

```
Unable to find a file at path [image1.jpg].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I have followed a few tutorials, but they all say the same thing and im really lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are renaming your file in the controller with `md5($image . microtime())` so you cannot assert that `image1.jpg` exists since you changed the name.

What you could do is let laravel name the file and then check that in your test:

In your Controller:

Replace `storeAs` with `store`, `store` will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
        foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
            $image->store('', 'uploads');
        }
    }
}
```

In your test:

To assert if the image exists we will use the same method to generate the unique ID as laravel does when saving the image. Replace 'image1.jpg' with `$image->hashName()` in your assertion.

```
public function testUserCanSuccessfullySubmitSingleImage(): void
{
    Storage::fake('uploads');

    $this->postJson('/upload', [
        'filename' => $image = UploadedFile::fake()->image('image1.jpg')
    ]);

    Storage::disk('uploads')->assertExists($image->hashName());
    Storage::disk('uploads')->assertMissing('missing.jpg');
}
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#storing-files):

> In web applications, one of the most common use-cases for storing
>   files is storing user uploaded files such as profile pictures, photos,
>   and documents. Laravel makes it very easy to store uploaded files
>   using the store method on an uploaded file instance. Call the store
>   method with the path at which you wish to store the uploaded file:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

    return $path;
}
```

> There are a few important things to note about this example. Note that
>   we only specified a directory name, not a file name. By default, the
>   store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. The
>   file's extension will be determined by examining the file's MIME type.
>   The path to the file will be returned by the store method so you can
>   store the path, including the generated file name, in your database.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh ... How could I miss that!! ... Thank you so much, i have been looking at this for days now wondering where I went wrong

Comment: @CodeSauce No the store method will only return a string with the path and filename, but you have access to the `UploadedFile` object where you can retrieve this information. `$image->getSize()` and `$image->getMimeType()` for example.

Comment: Sorry about this, but when I change the filesystem to 'root' => public_path('uploads') ... It seems to fail in that, why would that be?

Comment: @CodeSauce I would not store files in the `public_path`, you should store them in `storage/app/public` i.e. `storage_path('app/public')` and then create a [symlink](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk) to that directory if you want them to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Thats a good idea, so if i wanted to store my files in a directory called `uploads` what would my new filesystem look like? .. Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @CodeSauce You could just use the existing public disk that already exists by default and then add your directory to the store method. `store('uploads', 'public')`, or if you want to create your own disk the one in your question should be fine.

Comment: Well that makes sense as well!! ... Thank you .. I will give that a try

Comment: What about my tests, if i use disk('public') ... How do i add on the `uploads` directory

Comment: @CodeSauce Something like this: `Storage::disk('public')->assertExists("/uploads/{$image->hashName()}")`, not sure if you need the first slash though.

Comment: Ohhhh, there's an issue with the store method it seems `Call to a member function store() on string`